Problem deploying Google Cloud VM using Powershell
For a student project I need to deploy a VM on Google Cloud throught a powershell script that, whit no interaction, deploys an apache Http opened service.
in my script I already created all the network, subnetwork, api, ports and all needed to the machine to work.
The point is the startup sequence, inside the CreateVM function, the machine is created succesfully whit all settings correctly applied, but when i acess it throught SSH, theres no apache installed and/or running.
function CreateVm {
    $vmExists = gcloud compute instances describe $VmName --zone=$Zone --project=$ProjectId --format="value(name)" 2>$null
    if (-not $vmExists) {
        try {
            gcloud compute instances create $VmName `
                --zone=$Zone `
                --machine-type=e2-medium `
                --subnet=$SubnetName `
                --tags=$VmName `
                --metadata=startup-script='#! /bin/bash
                sudo apt-get update -qq
                sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apache2 ufw -qq < /dev/null
                sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
                sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
                sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
                sudo ufw --force enable
                sudo systemctl start apache2
                sudo systemctl enable apache2' `
                --project=$ProjectId `
                --quiet
            Write-Host "VM $VmName created successfully with Apache2 and firewall configuration." -ForegroundColor Green
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Failed to create VM $VmName : $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
            gcloud compute instances delete $VmName --zone=$Zone --quiet --project=$ProjectId
            return $false
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "VM $VmName already exists." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    return $true
}


I tried to redesign the script and the entire function a couple of times, and doing all the process of the script manually from the GCConsole but nothing seemed to change, only when i access direclty through ssh and i throw then commands by myself works, but in this case thats not valid.

Did you check the output of the startup script?
